# FCM Push notification how to get data and show custom banner

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on small app and I want to send my app the push notification. every thing is set up. and working fine. But now I want to send the custom notification and want to show the custom banner which shown when the fcm push notification is received.

I am doing it all easily in android but in iOS I have some confusions. here are some sort of things that I am not getting and do not know what to do

> **What I want: Following are my app requirements:**

- I want to show custom banner
- I Want to parse sent data by the server and want to save in UserDefaults

> **What I am doing: I am sending push from server and receiving banner but it is showing all data form the body Following is my app delegate**

```
    extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Did Receive")
    completionHandler()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Will Present")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    print("Did Receive remote notification")
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("Did Receive device token")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

}

/// Register for push notifications
func registerForPushNotification(){

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
    } else {

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

> **The Structure that is being sent by my server is as follow, and I want to show some data from {body} tag**

```
{
"to": "fBEk6eQ5I60:APA91bHR0IOZTBFJnFFxM9....GfeOGcoq-mBEUxj3ubab0x",
"priority": "high",
"force_start": 1,
"notification": {
    "body": {
        "UserId": 20054,
        "IsLogout": false,
        "DeviceId": "D58sada80-...-F8Asdasa147F",
        "Title": "Score App",
        "Message": "Today match suspended (Tue Oct-08-19 13:01)"
    },
    "title": "Score App",
    "content_available": true,
    "sound": "default",
    "priority": "high"
}
}
```

> **NOTE: I WANT THAT APP SHOW SAME BANNER WHEN IT IS IN FOREGROUND,BACKGROUND OR EVEN IT IS CLOSED**

Comment: No one knew about it?

Comment: can you show me how you did the banner for android